# awk match whole word

Tags: shell-script, awk, string, string-manipulation

I want to use `awk` to match whole words from text file. Including words bounded by non alphanumeric characters.

For example -

string to search for - ABC

Source file -

```
HHHABCCCCH
HHH ABC
HH(ABC)ASDAASD
HH,ABC-ASASDASD
```

Result -

```
HHH ABC
HH(ABC)ASDAASD
HH,ABC-ASASDASD
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to pass "ABC" as a variable instead of hardcoding it, use the matching operator:

```
awk -v word=ABC '$0 ~ "(^|[^[:alpha:]])" word "([^[:alpha:]]|$)"'
```

With gawk (other awks too?) you can use `\<` and `\>` to denote word boundaries, where a word is a sequence of letters, digits and underscore (I believe), so this will work for your example:

```
awk '/\<ABC\>/'
```

Comment: This is also available in BusyBox awk, even if built without glibc. It isn't available in nawk.

Comment: This won't work if the word is at the beginning of end of the line.

Comment: Fixed it ......

Comment: `\<` and `\>` are `gawk` extensions. With `POSIXLY_CORRECT=yes`, `gawk` reports `warning: regexp escape sequence \`\<' is not a known regexp operator`

Answer (score 6):

Use `\y` for word boundary, e.g.

`awk '/\yABC\y/'`

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html for more details.

Comment: That link is for gawk. I'm not sure if \y works with awk.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out - was having problems due to a typo

```
awk '/[^[:alpha:]]ABC[^[:alpha:]]/'
```

Comment: This will fail if ABC begins or ends the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '/( |\t|^|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+)ABC( |\t|$|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+)/' filename
```

Here:
`( |\t|^|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+)` means it can only have space/tab/non-alphanumeric character in before *ABC* or it is the beginning of the line.

Again,`( |\t|$|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+)` means it can only have space/tab/non-alphanumeric character in after *ABC* or it is the end of the line.