# Using awk to match whole words

Tags: awk

[Using this question](https://superuser.com/questions/349104/awk-match-whole-word) I've tried to match whole words with awk.

In my homerdir there's a file called `.bashrc`, but when I try to use:

```
ls -la | awk '$9 ~ /\<.bashrc\>/'
```

It doesn't show anything.

Also tried:

```
ls -la | awk '{if($9 ~ "^.bashrc" && $9 ~ "$.bashrc") echo $0}'
```

Still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the expected output?  From your question I don't see any reason to not simply use ls .bashrc or find . -name ".bashrc"

Comment: Assuming this is actually part of a larger problem (otherwise, I completely agree with Argonauts' suggestion), that regex syntax `\<` *is* supported by GNU awk (are you using another version?). Stupid suggestion maybe, but could you post the output of `ls -la` ?

Answer (score 1):

`~` is used for string comparison, it is not for exact match.

You could use `==`. Your command should be:

```
ls -la | awk '$9 == ".bashrc"'
```